# JavaScript Closure issue

Tags: javascript, function, google-maps, parameters, closures

Basically, I have to load two google maps, one dependent on the another. In my main div, I am locating certain points on world map and showing InfoWindow. Now On click of each of the InfoWindow, I need to load the same zoomed out place in another div. I have a bottom div, which will load this place with the latitude and longitude as center of this place and basically a zoomed out version of the place from main Div.

I have set up a fiddle and I am actually not able to pass the center of the Main Div to bottom Div,  google map.

Her is how I am doing this:

http://jsfiddle.net/refhat/SN8s4/2/

Help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you did not pass position to loadingAnotherMap. I have updated jsfiddle here:

http://jsfiddle.net/SN8s4/3/

Comment: So it should be loadingAnotherMap(marker.position);, I actually had loadingAnotherMap(position);
but how do the two differ programatically.

Comment: And also why does my infoWindow shows boxes instead of rounded corners, though I am using V3 of gmaps

Comment: in your jsfiddle, neither function definition, neither at the call time "position" is used..

Comment: on rounded corner stuff, I don't have much idea :(. I have not played around google maps a lot

Comment: but the bottom map again doesn't show zoomed out locations, Is there another error